# Where is Android Backup & Reset icon File

Tags: android, sdk, icons

I'm looking to reuse an icon that appears in `Android 4.2.2` settings `"Backup & reset"`. (see screenshot)
I don't manage to find the source file of this icon among the Android `SDK files`.

Where is this file Located?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where is this file located?

It is located in [the Settings app](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_settings).

Alas, since they are white icons (designed for use on a dark background), I cannot readily show one here. :-)

Answer (score 1):

i find file from @CommonsWare answer on settings app drawable folder below link for **drawable-hdpi**

https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_settings/blob/master/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_settings_backup.png

**drawable-mdpi:**

https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_settings/blob/master/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_settings_backup.png

Comment: Thank you for the direct link